# How to handle it when a constructor isn't called with new in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen pattern in a constructor that works like this:

```
function Animal(name) {
    if ( !(this instanceof Animal) ) {
        return new Animal(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

Or a more general form:

```
function Animal(name) {
    if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) ) {
        return new arguments.callee(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

so that if `Animal()` is called without the `new` keyword by mistake, then it still works by invoking `new Animal(name)` inside the code.  But I wonder why tolerate bad calling code?  Won't the following be more desirable?

```
function Animal(name) {
    if ( !(this instanceof Animal) ) {
        // throw an exception, alert, or console.log or console.error
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

So that the programmer can immediately correct the calling code.

But I wonder for each approach, what if

1. What if the exception is caught but just ignored at some level of the call stack?
2. If it is an alert, what if it is in a loop that runs a thousand time, and the browser has no way to let the user choose not to show any more alert, then the alert will pop up a thousand time.
3. console.log or console.error... what if the programmer didn't have the console open?  Then the bug can possibly slip through and get pushed to the production server.

One way may be to use JSLint?  But what if the code already have a few thousand lines and many many warnings showing in JSLint, and we cannot fix all warnings right at the moment, then what may be a good way to implement the constructor well at the moment?

Comment: Personal styles/choices. If there's some code that rarely gets used, and it slips through the cracks, it wouldn't be pleasant if that bug was encountered in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question seems to be how to deal with constructors not being called with `new` when they should. There are obvious answers:

1. Write for ECMAScript ed 3 but use strict mode for development so that most (but not necessarily all) such errors will caught immediately. Most code being written for the web now should run in both strict and non–strict mode.
2. Use thorough unit tests
3. Use  a linter

It seems to me that if code passes testing where the object returned by a constructor is actually the global object rather than an instance, either the testing was rubbish or a constructor shouldn't have been used in the first place.

In the vast majority of cases, there's no need to use constructors in javascript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I for one hate it when the `new` keyword is strewn all over the place. By following standard convention, all my class names start with an uppercase character to distinguish them from regular functions.

jQuery uses these extensively with all their constructor functions (e.g. [`Event`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L595)).
I think it makes for far more elegant code.

---

**P.S.** Don't use `arguments.callee`. It's been deprecated.

Comment: you mean you prefer to call constructor functions without using `new`, so the constructor is written the same as the first example in the original question?

Comment: @動靜能量 - Correct. I always call my constructor functions without the `new` keyword, and have the constructor take care of it. Having the first letter in the name capitalized helps with the reading.

Comment: @JosephSilber—[arguments.callee](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) **is not** deprecated, it's just unavailable in strict mode. Calling constructors without `new` but making them behave like constructors anyway makes code harder to understand and encourages misuse.

Comment: @RobG - Am I wrong in assuming that anything unavailable in strict mode is effectively deprecated?

Comment: @JosephSilber—some have said that, but I don't see any support for that opinion in ECMA-262. A specification feature should only be described as deprecated if the specification uses the term (and hence its meaning is likely to be defined by the specification too). While strict mode encourages developers not to use certain features, "deprecated" to me means that the feature will be removed in a future version and is a much stronger deterrent. Also, there doesn't seem to be an intention to deprecate or remove *callee* in the [ES6 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html).

Comment: @RobG - I stand corrected. Regardless, I still think that anything unavailable in strict mode should generally be avoided. Additionally, the only reason for not allowing `callee` in strict mode, is because it's a lot of work for the JavaScript engine to keep track of it *regardless of whether you actually use it*. In other words, refraining to use `callee` is *only* beneficial if it'll eventually be dropped completely (I know. Highly unlikely. But still).